# In Angular I want to project the nativeElement to another component without using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, angular-template

In Angular I want to project (**Transclude**) a **nativeElement** to another component without using innerHTML.

Currently I'm trying to do this using **ngComponentOutlet** using a child component that has an **ng-content**.

I want to load the component and send html data to it all rendered so I dont need to use **innerHTML** to compile it to HTML.

Reason for this is, innerHTML looses the **bindings**.

**This is my attempt:**

**My Parent Component:**

```
import { Component, ContentChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

import { TableRowComponent } from '../table-row/table-row.component';
import { TableCellComponent } from '../table-cell/table-cell.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'ls-table-body',
  template: `
    <ng-container>
      <tr ls-table-row *ngFor="let row of rows">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let cell of cells">

          <ng-container  *ngComponentOutlet="tableCellComponent; content: [[cell.elem.nativeElement]]"></ng-container>

        </ng-container>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./table-body.component.scss']
})
export class TableBodyComponent {
  @ContentChildren(TableRowComponent) rows: QueryList<TableRowComponent>;
  @ContentChildren(TableCellComponent) cells: QueryList<TableCellComponent>;

  public tableCellComponentComponent = TableCellComponent;
}
```

**My Child Component called TableCellComponent:**

```
import { Component, HostBinding, Input, ContentChildren, ViewEncapsulation, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '[ls-table-cell]',
  template: `
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./table-cell.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class TableCellComponent {
  @HostBinding() @Input('class') classList = 'ls-table-cell';
  @ContentChildren(TableCellComponent) cells: QueryList<TableCellComponent>;
  @Input() span: number;
  @Input() data: any;
}
```

**Outcome I'm looking for:**

I'm looking to compile the HTML - as I cannot use innerHTML due to the bindings getting removed - so I've optted for the ngComponentOutlet solution using ng-content - as I believe that compiles my HTML I pass through using cell.elem.nativeElement.

I'm also open to alternatives

Comment: Take a look at `@angular/cdk`: https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview. It's developed by `@angular/material` team and wraps ngComponentOutlet in a more robust api.

Comment: Can I have an example of portal please - I've tried it before and couldnt get it working @jpavel

Comment: There's an example on the link I've posted: https://stackblitz.com/angular/emyllbnnlkm?file=app%2Fcdk-portal-overview-example.ts

Comment: @jpavel I just tried portals and they dont render html. So for example: rows[0].elem.nativeElement.children[0].innerHTML renders as a string and not html. And I can't use the  [innerHTML] due to the bindings being removed when using it.

Comment: Oh, now I got what you want. Portals really don't do that. Isn't it possible for you to try another approach? In fact, @angular wasn't designed thinking of the developer manually parsing a string in order to generate a component from it.

Comment: @jpavel yeh I just want to render my nativeElement innerHTML string to HTML. I've used this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-component but no luck using that either. Still renders as a string. Reason I cant used [innerHTML] is because it removes the bindings eg click events. Anything else I can try?